# Using both aria-hidden="true" and aria-labelledby attributes in the same field

Tags: html, django, dom, wai-aria

I understand the functionality of both aria-hidden="true" attributes and aria-labelledby in the sense that the prior attribute hides the contents of an element and its child-elements from screen-readers (supposedly including aria-labelledby and aria-labelled), and that the latter attribute gives an element its accessible name based on another element's aria-label.

However, I am faced by a contradiction in a Django course I am completing.

https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxN1rhn70sw6fPvRdhpAFZv0KnPBz7J5-y

(I have also attached a snippet of the uncompleted code below.)

Here, the creator of the course includes both aria-hidden="true" attributes and aria-labelledby attributes simultaneously. According to what I understood, the inclusion of aria-labelledby makes no difference. So what is the point of including it?

TLDR: Does the data of aria-labelledby still appear in screen readers when aria-hidden="true" or did the course creator make a mistake?

```
                                <div class="modal" id="#myModal{{student.id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="">
                                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                      <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        </button>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding and explanation of the two attributes is good. There might be two little details to add:

1. You can provide a label for anything, but it doesn’t really matter if the element is neither interactive (focusable), nor a landmark or important part of the document
2. Attributes can be changed by scripts, so the `aria-hidden` can be removed later

The code you provided does not really demonstrate the issue you explained, but it looks like a [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/).

In the Bootstrap docs, the first line goes like this:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

So I believe this is what you are referring to. It’s a common pattern with dialogs that they are initially hidden and then revealed by means of a script. If you open the modal dialog demo in Bootstrap, you will notice the following attributes being changed:

```
- aria-hidden
+ style="display: block; …"
+ role="dialog"
+ aria-modal="true"
```

### Why is `aria-hidden` there in the first place?

The decision of which attributes to expect in the base markup, and which to add when the script is executed, depends on different factors.

Here, it is probably due to the fact that the script might still be loading when the user navigates the document. By applying `display: none` in CSS, and `aria-hidden` in HTML, it’s made sure that the dialog is not exposed to anyone, until the script is loaded and the dialog button pressed.

Once the dialog is open, it needs a name, so the `aria-labelledby` attribute comes into play.